# Get block #id from page with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I get part of code in block #id like     `.load('url #id')`    ,but `.load()` doesn't get script inside #id

```
function ocmenu(linkurl) {
  $.ajax({
      url: linkurl,
          cache: true
      }).done(function (html) {
          $('.new').append(html);
  });
}
```

`html.filter('#id')` doesn't work

Comment: What are you talking about? What is #id, where is #id?

Comment: The question is absolutely illogical, what are you talking about even ?

Comment: #id is block `<div id="id"></div>`, I need get all what inside that block like function load(), but load dont get <scripts>

Comment: If I understand the question correctly. You have discovered that using a sector on Load causes it to filter out any Javascript inside the selected item. That is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works:

```
$.get(linkurl,function(resp)
{
    content = $("#id",resp);
    $('.new').append(content);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `jQuery.getScript()` method:

**Description:** *Loads a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.*

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Alternatively   you can use `data type:text` on your `AJAX call`, which will return a plain text string.

i.e:

```
function ocmenu(linkurl) {
    $.ajax({
      url: linkurl,
      dataType: 'text',
      cache: true
    }).done(function (html) {
      $('.new').append(html);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the OP just wants to get the element with the ID passed in the .load() function, not a script.

Comment: His question is pretty unclear because he also mentions `but .load() doesn't get script inside #id`...

Comment: The whole point of the question was that he wants part of the download page (defined by ID=) and also any scripts within it. Yes, you cannot use load(selector) to do that as it strips any scripts.

Comment: My answer was a day's worth of commercial solution (that actually worked for the specific problem asked) and it also got down-voted *now deleted to avoid more ignorant voting*. It is a shame there is no requirement for down-voters to actually understand the answers themselves! :) Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

try the below code snippet

```
function ocmenu(linkurl) {
  $.ajax({
      url: linkurl,
          cache: true
      }).done(function (html) {
          $('.new').append("<div id='id'>foo</div>").append(html);
  });
}
```

now

```
$("div").filter('#id')
```

will return desired result

Comment: The #id is part of the load filtering and defines the part of the download to return. It is not part of the result he is after.